# Running python script on client side using Vue.js

Tags: python, vue.js, client

Due to computation limitations, I have to run a python script on the client side.

Actually, my website is using Vue.js for frontend and Django for backend.

Would you know how I could run this specific task only on the client side (Python + Vue.js) without having to interact with the server ?

All the sites that found only talked about doing the computation on the server side by using Flask or Django.

Thank you for your advice.

Kind regards.

Comment: What does your python script actually do? The problem is that I believe most (if any) browsers don't have the ability to run python on the client side. Can you port your script to javascript?

Comment: The python scripts process the pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

There's some tools that let you do this... I've never used them and they're fairly uncommon. https://skulpt.org/ or https://pythontips.com/2019/05/22/running-python-in-the-browser/

In theory, you would need to port the Python code into JavaScript or WebAssembly (WebAssembly will likely be harder). But this will depend largely on the code you're trying to execute.

If I were in your shoes, depending on my experience, I would rethink the problem or reimplement the code in JavaScript.

The Vue part isn't really relevant, you'll have this issue with Vanilla JS or React.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have a look!